# How to Enforce Order of Arguments in Constructor [Java]

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, persistence, pojo

I'm writing code that reads values from props file and attempts to automatically create corresponding POJO instance.

```
// Code below will retrieve keys in order they are annotated in class.. this may or may not be same order as they appear in constructor.. (this is my problem)
String[] keys = ReflectionX.getDeclaredMethodsWithPropXFileRWBindByNameAnnotationSorted(c, PropXFileRWBindByName.class);

ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    // The code below retrieves String values from file
    // I will repeat the code to retrieve ArrayList<String> values

    for (String key : keys) {



        String value = propsX.getPropValueAsStr(key);
        objectList.add(value);

        Constructor<?>[] constructors = c.getConstructors();

        Object[] objs = objectList.toArray();

        Constructor<?> finalConstructor = null;

        for (Constructor<?> constructor : constructors) {

            if (constructor.isAnnotationPresent(PropsXConstructor.class)) {
                finalConstructor = constructor;
                break;
            }

        }


        if (finalConstructor != null) {

            P record = (P) finalConstructor.newInstance(objs);
            recordList.add(record);

        } 

    }
```

The code above will retrieve the 'key' of any field annotated with @PropXFileRWBindByName and will then retrieve the value from properties file. It then attempts to create instance of given object using `newInstance(objs);`

The issue is that I want to enforce the order of arguments in the constructor. In other words, the keys are being retrieved in the same order they appear in class. Obviously, when I initially created the constructor the order of arguments mimicked the order they appear in class. But how can I enforce this so that it the order of arguments in constructor always matches the order I get in `keys`? In other words, I want to enforce that the constructor arguments must always appear in a specific order (perhaps via annotations?) so that if they are changed IDE should display error.
In my specific example constructor looks something like this:

```
constructor(String str1, String str2, String str3, ArrayList<String> arr1, ArrayList<String> arr2, String str4)
```

When I retrieve values from file I need to know the exact order of arguments and generate constructor accordingly.

My question is how can I **enforce** that order of arguments in constructor is always consistent with the way they appear in class so I match the arguments correctly when creating new instance via `Reflection`?

Thanks!

Comment: But order of constructor argument do not change, so what exactly you want to enforce here? I think all you need is a flag to compiler to preserve argument names, so you can just use parameters of constructor.`-parameters`

Comment: `keys` is an array that only exist at runtime. You cannot enforce at compile-time that the parameters are in an order only existing at runtime. Just to make that clear: there is nothing in the specification saying anything about the order of field information in a class file, i.e. it is not guaranteed to reflect the order of the source code declarations, so since the source code order is not present in the class file, nothing `ReflectionX.getDeclaredMethodsWithPropXFileRWBindByNameAnnotationSorted`ever does with it can guaranty you to get the array in source code order.